# Flatten a deeply nested data structure of arrays, objects + strings into a list of data items while mapping the former parent-child relationship too

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Restructuring array of objects to new array

**Problem**

There’s an array of objects that contains plain strings and might contain nested arrays as well. We want to create a new Array that will contain a node for each item in the array and separate nodes for each array item connected to its parent. Each parent node should have the following structure:

```
{
    id: uuidv4(),
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    data: { label: <item data goes here> }
}
```

Each array node with the following schema above, should also have a connection edge item added to the array with the following properties:

```
{
    id: ‘e<array item Id>-<parentId>’,
    source: <array item Id>,
    target: <parentId>,
}
```

**Example**

We have the following array of objects for example:

```
[
  {
    "author": "John Doe",
    "age": 26,
    "books": [
      {
        "title": "Book 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Book 2",
        "chapters": [
          {
            "title": "No Way Home",
            "page": 256
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected output is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "data": {
      "label": {
        "author": "John Doe",
        "age": 26,
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "data": {
      "label": "books" // key of array
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "data": {
      "label": {
        "title": "Book 1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "data": {
      "label": {
        "title": "Book 2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "data": {
      "label": "chapters" // key of array
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "data": {
      "label": {
        "title": "No Way Home",
        "page": 256
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "e2-1",
    "source": "2",
    "target": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "e3-2",
    "source": "3",
    "target": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "e4-2",
    "source": "4",
    "target": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "e5-4",
    "source": "5",
    "target": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "e6-5",
    "source": "6",
    "target": "5"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello. What is the problem with your code? If you don't show us have you have tried so far we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would not be answering if there was not already a good answer.  Please, on StackOverflow, always show your own attempts and explain where you got stuck.  But since there is already an answer, I think this version might be a bit simpler.

Second, I'm assuming this output format is some sort of directed graph, that the first half is your list of vertices and the second half a list of edges.  If so I don't know if your output format is constrained here.  But if you had the option, I would think a better structure would be an object with `vertices` and `edges` properties, each containing an array.  You might then not need the edges' ids.  And the code could also be simplified.

This version first converts to an intermediate structure like this:

```js
[
    {id: "1", data: {label: {author: "John Doe", age: 26}}, children: [
        {id: "2", data: {label: "books"}, children: [
            {id: "3", data: {label: {title: "Book 1"}}, children: []}, 
            {id: "4", data: {label: {title: "Book 2"}}, children: [
                {id: "5", data: {label: "chapters"}, children: [
                    {id: "6", data: {label: {title: "No Way Home"}}, children: []}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
]
```

Then we flatten that structure into the first section of the output and use it to calculate the relationships (edges?) between nested nodes to go in the second section.

The code looks like this:

```js
const transform = (input) => {
  const extract = (os, nextId = ((id) => () => String (++ id)) (0)) => os .map ((o) => ({
    id: nextId(), 
    data: {label: Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .filter (([k, v]) => !Array .isArray (v)))},
    children: Object .entries (o) .filter (([k, v]) => Array .isArray (v)) .flatMap (([k, v]) => [
      {id: nextId(), data: {label: k}, children: extract (v, nextId)},
    ])
  }))
  
  const relationships = (xs) =>
    xs .flatMap (({id: target, children = []}) => [
      ... children .map (({id: source}) => ({id: `e${source}-${target}`, source, target})),
      ... relationships (children),
    ])
  
  const flatten = (xs) => 
    xs .flatMap (({children, ...rest}) => [rest, ... flatten (children)])
    
  const res = extract (input)
  
  return [...flatten (res), ... relationships (res)] 
}

const input = [{author: "John Doe", age : 26, books: [{title: "Book 1"}, {title: "Book 2", chapters: [{title: "No Way Home", page: 256}]}]}]

console .log (transform (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We use three separate recursive functions.  One does the recursive extract into that intermediate format.  Along the way, it adds `id` nodes using a `nextId` stateful function (something I usually avoid, but seems to simplify things here.)  Then `flatten` simply recursively lifts the children to sit alongside their parents.  And `relationships` (again recursively) uses the ids of the parent- and child-nodes to add an edge node.

Using these three separate recursive calls is probably less efficient than some other solutions, but I think it leads to much cleaner code.

Comment: _"Using these three separate recursive calls is probably less efficient than some other solutions, but I think it leads to much cleaner code."_ ... That's true in every aspect. And since clean code, in my opinion, counts more than doing everything with a single self recursive function, I recommend this to be the accepted answer. And my upvote on this anyhow.

Comment: @PeterSeliger: I didn't look closely at  your code when writing this.  I glanced at it, thought that it involved more code than the problem warranted, and tried my own.  This one was frustrating, because I'm sure there is an elegant one-pass solution that I simply couldn't find.  As to clean code, it counts more than anything... but only if I'm passing fixed criteria like performance SLAs and team coding conventions.  But often enough it does have to defer to one of these, and ugliness rules.  Off to read your code now!

Answer (score 2):

One has to choose a self recursive approach which in a generic way can process both, array-items and object-entries. Also, while the recursive process takes place, one not only has to create and collect the ***consecutively/serially numbered** (the incremented `id` value) **data nodes***, but one in addition needs to keep track of every data node's `parent` reference in order to finally **concatenate** the **list of `edge` items** (as the OP calls it) to the **list of data nodes**.

```js
function flattenStructureRecursively(source = [], result = [], tracker = {}) {
  let {
    parent = null, edgeItems = [],
    getId = (id => (() => ++id))(0),
  } = tracker;

  const createEdgeItem = (id, pid) => ({
    id: `e${ id }-${ pid }`,
    source: id,
    target: pid,
  });
  const putNodeData = node => {
    result.push(node);

    if (parent !== null) {
      edgeItems.push(createEdgeItem(node.id, parent.id));
    }
    // every data node is a parent entity too.
    parent = node;
  };

  if (Array.isArray(source)) {
    result.push(
      ...source.flatMap(item =>
        flattenStructureRecursively(item, [], {
          getId, parent, edgeItems,
        })
      )
    );
  } else {
    let {
      dataNode,
      childEntries,
    } = Object
      .entries(source)
      .reduce(({ dataNode, childEntries }, [key, value]) => {
        if (value && (Array.isArray(value) || (typeof value === 'object'))) {
          // collect any object's iterable properties.

          childEntries.push([key, value]);
        } else {
          // aggregate any object's non iterable
          // properties at data node level.
          (dataNode ??= {

            id: getId(),
            data: { label: {} }

          }).data.label[key] = value;
        }
        return { dataNode, childEntries };

      }, { dataNode: null, childEntries: [] });

    if (dataNode !== null) {
      putNodeData(dataNode);
    }
    childEntries
      .forEach(([key, value]) => {
        // every object's iterable property is supposed
        // to be created as an own parent entity.

        dataNode = {
          id: getId(),
          data: { label: key },
        };
        putNodeData(dataNode);

        result.push(
          ...flattenStructureRecursively(value, [], {
            getId, parent, edgeItems,
          })
        );
      });
  }
  if (parent === null) {
    // append all additionally collected edge items
    // in the end of all the recursion.

    result.push(...edgeItems);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  flattenStructureRecursively([{
    author: "John Doe",
    pseudonym: "J.D.",
    books: [{
      title: "Book 1",
    }, {
      title: "Book 2",
      chapters: [{
        title: "No Way Home",
        page: 256,
      }],
    }],
    age: 26,
  }])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I've tried it and it almost worked as how it is intended. However there was two issues I've ran into. The first thing is, when there is another element in the input array there are multiple elements with same ID in the new array, another issue is not every key of the object is supposed to be a node but array elements only, thus I've updated the example to make it more clear. I'd be so grateful if you could look into it again.

Comment: @AykutSaraç ... Done. The last changes do cover the new requirements. The final version also is more robust in terms of how the recursion handles less well ordered object entries.

Comment: @AykutSaraç ... There was yet another implementation change which now is entirely agnostic to any given/provided data structure.

Comment: Well, regardless of whether this code is less simple than my version, it's still an impressive *tour de force* to manage this with a single pass.  *Me hat's off to the duke!*

Comment: @ScottSauyet ... Thanks for coming up with the `nextId` approach. Applying it to my implementation too did help with cleaning up the above code.

Comment: Oh, I had assumed we both hit on the same technique.  It works, but something about it bothers me.